# Вывод вариации размеров в виде таблицы

Tags: атрибуты

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, такой вывод вариации можно как-то реализовать плагином?Есть подобное? Или все руками писать?Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]